# Comparison test and Weierstrass M-test

Tags: real-analysis

So I kinda confused about these two tests, because they look pretty similar to me. Does the only difference between them is that the first one used to decided if one series converges or not, and the latter one used to determine if a series converges uniformly or not?

Comment: Weierstrass M test is for a series of functions.

Comment: Oops you are right, but they are basically the same thing right?

Comment: These tests are no good for the "or not" decision

Comment: I understand. They can only used to test if a series converges, but they can't be used to test if a series diverges. correct?

Comment: Yes that's right.